# Adding a plot rendering option to an InteractiveComplexHeatmap R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, interactive, complexheatmap

I'm trying to expand [InteractiveComplexHeatmap's](https://jokergoo.github.io/InteractiveComplexHeatmap/articles/shiny_dev.html) simple example of a clickable heatmap. Ideally, I'd like the `InteractiveComplexHeatmapOutput` to include a plot in the output generated upon a click event, but that seems too complicated so for now I'm trying to include a side panel which allows the user to select a heatmap row and column labels, which will generate that plot.

In the example below, I have a `gene` x `pair` expression matrix (`mat`, where `pair` represents the combined expression value of the gene from a treatment - control paired sample), which is used to generate the heatmap, and a `data.frame` (`fc.df`) with an `effect.size` and `effect.size.error` values for each `gene` in each `pair`. The plot I would like to add is a `ggplot2` `geom_bar` + `geom_errorbar` showing for the selected `gene` and `pair` the corresponding `effect.size` and `effect.size.error`.

Here's my code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(InteractiveComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))


set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10000,0,1),nrow = 1000, ncol = 10,dimnames = list(paste0("gene",1:1000),paste0("pair",1:10)))
fc.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(paste0("pair",1:10), function(p){
   data.frame(gene = paste0("gene",1:1000), pair = p, effect.size = rnorm(1000,0,1), effect.size.error = sd(rnorm(1000,0,0.5)))
}))
ht <- Heatmap(mat,show_row_names=F)
ht <- draw(ht)


server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  makeInteractiveComplexHeatmap(input, output, session, ht, "heatmap")
  
  output$gene <- renderUI({
    selectInput("gene", "Select gene", choices = unique(rownames(mat)), multiple = F)
  })

  output$pair <- renderUI({
    selectInput("pair", "Select pair", choices = unique(colnames(mat)), multiple = F)
  })
  
  output$effectPlot <- reactive({
    req(input$gene, input$pair)
    plot.df <- dplyr::filter(fc.df, gene == input$gene & pair == input$pair)
    bar.plot <- ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = gene, y = effect.size)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge()) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = effect.size-effect.size.error, ymax = effect.size+effect.size.error),width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
      theme_minimal()+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
    renderPlot(effectPlot)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Pairs Effects Explorer",windowTitle="Pairs Effects Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#loadmessage {position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 100%;color: #000000;background-color: #CCFF66;z-index: 105;}"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",tags$div("In Progress...",id="loadmessage")),
      uiOutput("gene"),
      uiOutput("pair"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      InteractiveComplexHeatmapOutput(heatmap_id="heatmap",title1="Expression Heatmap",title3="Gene-Pair Info",
                                                width1=800,height1=800,width3=400,height3=300,
                                                action="click",response="click",output_ui_float=F),
      plotOutput("effectPlot")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The issues/questions are:

1. It does not render the `effectPlot` - how do I get that to appear?
2. I would like the rendered `effectPlot` to appear either i the side panel below the selection lists, or on the right side of the main panel, below the area dedicated to the sub-heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

This renders the `effectPlot` in the side panel below the selection lists:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(InteractiveComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))



set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10000,0,1),nrow = 1000, ncol = 10,dimnames = list(paste0("gene",1:1000),paste0("pair",1:10)))
fc.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(paste0("pair",1:10), function(p){
   data.frame(gene = paste0("gene",1:1000), pair = p, effect.size = rnorm(1000,0,1), effect.size.error = sd(rnorm(1000,0,0.5)))
}))
ht <- Heatmap(mat,show_row_names=F)
ht <- draw(ht)


server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  makeInteractiveComplexHeatmap(input, output, session, ht, "heatmap")
  
  output$gene <- renderUI({
    selectInput("gene", "Select gene", choices = unique(rownames(mat)), multiple = F)
  })

  output$pair <- renderUI({
    selectInput("pair", "Select pair", choices = unique(colnames(mat)), multiple = F)
  })
  
  output$effectPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$gene, input$pair)
    plot.df <- dplyr::filter(fc.df, gene == input$gene & pair == input$pair)
    ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = gene, y = effect.size)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge()) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = effect.size-effect.size.error, ymax = effect.size+effect.size.error),width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
      theme_minimal()+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Pairs Effects Explorer",windowTitle="Pairs Effects Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#loadmessage {position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 100%;color: #000000;background-color: #CCFF66;z-index: 105;}"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",tags$div("In Progress...",id="loadmessage")),
      uiOutput("gene"),
      uiOutput("pair"),
      plotOutput("effectPlot",height="200px"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      InteractiveComplexHeatmapOutput(heatmap_id="heatmap",title1="Expression Heatmap",title3="Gene-Pair Info",
                                                width1=800,height1=800,width3=400,height3=300,
                                                action="click",response="click",output_ui_float=F)
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```